# How to avoid the double arrows in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

With the following code

```
library(igraph)

actors <- data.frame(name=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("a", "a", "b", "b",
                               "b", "c", "d","d",
                               "g","e","g","d"),
                        to  =c("d", "e", "c", "e", 
                               "g", "f", "f", "g",
                               "h","b","d","a"),
                        weight = c(14,30,25,3,5,6,4,13,2,6,10,10))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
test.layout <- layout_(g,with_dh(weight.edge.lengths = edge_density(g)/1000))
plot(g,vertex.size=30,edge.arrow.size= 0.5,edge.label = relations$weight,
     layout = test.layout)
```

I produce the weighted directed graph
[image]
I would like to avoid the double arrows at the end of some edges. I would like to see, instead, two different edges (for example from d to a and from a to d).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not set the random seed before generating your layout so I do not get exactly your layout. Nervertheless,  you can get two separate edges, by using the `edge.curved` argument to `igraph.plot`.

```
ENDS = ends(g, E(g))
Curv = rep(F, nrow(ENDS))
for(i in 1:nrow(ENDS)) {
    Curv[i] = are.connected(g, ENDS[i,2], ENDS[i,1]) }

plot(g,vertex.size=30,edge.arrow.size=0.5,edge.label = relations$weight,
     layout = test.layout, edge.curved=Curv)
```

[image: Graph with curved edges]

Comment: Great answer, beautiful plot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `edge.curved=TRUE` directly if you don't mind ***all*** curved edges (but you can customize your plot as you want, and the answer by [@G5W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606244/12158757) looks nicer)

```
plot(g,
  vertex.size = 30, edge.arrow.size = 0.5, edge.label = relations$weight,
  layout = test.layout,
  edge.curved = TRUE
)
```

[image]